# Issue in creating App using Monax :- Contract not found in JSON

Tags: contract-development, eris-industries, monax

I am trying to create applications using Monax.
I am using the reference given in Monax for developing app https://github.com/monax/hello-doug.
I have created `hello-chain` as mentioned in their Read-me.
I am trying to start app using ```npm install``,but it returns the following error.

```
> hello-doug@0.0.2 start /home/maria/Documents/Monax-Sample-App/hello-doug
> node app.js

[2017-11-27 15:28:28.148] [INFO] [default] - Initializing LOG4JS ...
[2017-11-27 15:28:28.170] [INFO] [default] - Configuring logger for category: Main, level: INFO
[2017-11-27 15:28:28.173] [INFO] Main - Starting platform ...
[2017-11-27 15:28:28.707] [INFO] monax.db - Connection established with node at URL http://localhost:1337/rpc
[2017-11-27 15:28:28.708] [INFO] monax.app - Creating a new application manager from JSON:    {"DealManager":"","defaultAddr":"4B7AA356E0A413B076E71B5E4CAB7C793410E480"}
[2017-11-27 15:28:28.708] [DEBUG] hello.contracts - Detected 1 contracts to be loaded: DealManager
[2017-11-27 15:28:28.709] [DEBUG] monax.app - Loading contract DealManager
[2017-11-27 15:28:28.712] [ERROR] Main - Unexpected error initializing the application: Contract not found in JSON: DealManager
```

The generated epm.otput.json file is as follows :-

```
 {
   "DealManager": "",
   "defaultAddr": "4B7AA356E0A413B076E71B5E4CAB7C793410E480"
}
```

I have found a json in the sqlsol folder.

How can I resolve this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the contracts did not deploy correctly, so the application is missing the DealManager smart contract to talk to on the chain. The DealManager entry in the epm.output.json should show an address, if it was deployed successfully.

What was the output of the `monax pkgs do ...` command? Any errors?

Comment: monax pkgs do -c hello-chain -a $fullAccount

*****Executing Job*****

Job Name                                      defaultAddr
Writing [epm.output.json] to current directory    It returns the following message with the aboive output

Comment: This is the right answer, there was a problem with the contract deployment, that's why there is not address for the DealManager. If you're using the examples on the site with monax v0.18 then remove the lines in the epm yaml file that are just `job:` and you should be gtg

Comment: @CaseyKuhlman I am using Monax CLI version :- 0.18.0 . I am following the tutorial https://monax.io/docs/getting-started/ .As you mentioned, I have updated the epm.yaml by job: ..It returns the following error.   ```Sorry, the marmots were unable to load the monax jobs file. Please check your path: While parsing config: yaml: line 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Comment: @CaseyKuhlman This is for your reference regarding versions ```SERVICE              ON     VERSION
compilers            *      0.18.0
keys                 *      0.17.0
                                                    
CHAIN                ON     VERSION
hello-chain-test     -      0.17.0
advchain             -      0.17.0
advchain2            -      0.17.0
firstchain           *      0.17.0 ```.

Comment: @BTCETHswap Any suggestions regarding this issue?

Comment: @CrissiMariamRobert to fix see my comment above regarding removing the line(s) with the `job:` field.

Comment: @CaseyKuhlman I have omitted the job: field..Still it show issues...I will post another question regarding it.

Comment: @CaseyKuhlman  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31956/monax-issue-in-executing-job-configuration-file